# Select an item from dropdownlist on a webpage by VBA

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I want a VBA code to convert currency on XE currency converter site and give me result. I am not getting how to select a currency from list. Below is attacched my code:

```
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Set ie = New InternetExplorer

ie.Visible = True
ie.navigate "http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/"
Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.StatusBar = "loading web page...."
DoEvents
Loop
Set html = ie.document
Dim drp As HTMLFormElement
html.getElementById("amount").Value = 100
'html.getElementById("from").Value = "Euro"
Set drp = html.getElementById("from_sc")
drp.Click
```

Comment: This has been asked and answered [many, many](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vba+ie+dropdown) times on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a shot and let me know if I've missed anything. Change the fields containing `GBP - British Pound` or `EUR - Euro` according to your need.

```
Sub Get_Result()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, html As HTMLDocument
    Dim post As Object, elem As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/"
        Do Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Loop
        Set html = .document
    End With

    html.getElementById("amount").Value = 100
    html.getElementById("from_sc").Click

    For Each post In html.getElementsByClassName("ac_odd ac_recent")
        If InStr(post.innerText, "EUR - Euro") > 0 Then post.Click: Exit For
    Next post

    html.getElementById("to_sc").Click

    For Each elem In html.getElementById("to_scroller").getElementsByClassName("ac_even ac_recent")
        If InStr(elem.innerText, "GBP - British Pound") > 0 Then elem.Click: Exit For
    Next elem

    html.getElementById("ucc_go_btn_svg").Click
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Shahin. It's working perfectly fine.

Comment: If it works, make sure to accept it as an answer by ticking the grayed out checkmark next to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Shahin, may I request you use block form, not `:`, for multi-statement `Then` or `Else` blocks in answers to new askers?  Yes, [MSDN is clear](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/ifthenelse-statement) that, e.g., `elem.Click: Exit For` above is the controlled block.  However, I can imagine a newbie OP being confused about whether the `Exit For` is part of the `Then` block or not.  (I actually hadn't seen this style before!)  I'm asking for purely selfish reasons, to make my life easier as an answerer :) .  Thanks for considering this request!  Happy hacking!