# How to select an specific item on a drop down list on ASPX site

Tags: html, vba, excel, dom, web-scraping

I want it to be as if the user had clicked on "Dental." However, when I run the following code, nothing happens.
I want it to be as if the user had clicked on "Dental." However, when I run the following code, nothing happens.
I want it to be as if the user had clicked on "Dental."  However, when I run the following code, nothing happens.

```
'Public Sub IE_Search_and_Extract()  
    'Dim URL As String
    'Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    'Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
    'Dim response As String
    'response = MsgBox("Login ", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "login")
    'If response = vbYes Then
     '   URL = " "
    'Else
    'End If

    'Set IE = Get_IE_Window(URL)
    'If IE Is Nothing Then
     '   Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    'End If

   ' With IE
    '    SetForegroundWindow .hwnd
     '   .navigate URL
      '  .Visible = True
       ' While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        '    DoEvents
        'Wend

      '  '.document.getElementById("btnLogin").Click

'      '  While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
'            DoEvents
'        Wend
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:5"))
        Set HTMLdoc = .document
    End With

    'Dim post As Object, elem As Object
    'For Each post In HTMLdoc.getElementsByClassName("cboItem")
     '   If InStr(post.innerText, "Dental") > 0 Then post.Click: Exit For
    'Next post

'End Sub
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! We're here to help with already existing code (or attempted research), typically people won't create code for you, if you need some code written for you, you may want to check out some paid services. Please refer to [How-To-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @ Maldred. Thanks for your suggestion. I am sorry that I didn't include my code at that point of time. Now I have included the code I have created so far. I have also gone through various posts and try to solve this problem before posting this question. However I didn't get success.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to synthesize a click on "Dental"?  You want it to be as if the user had clicked on "Dental"?  Or do you mean that you want to know what item the user has already clicked on?  **Also**, what problem are you having with your existing code?  What happens when you run it?

Comment: @cxw I want it to be as if the user had clicked on "Dental". When I run this code, nothing is happening and I am not getting error on VBE.

Comment: Thanks!  I have edited your question to include that information.  Allow me to suggest that you make such edits yourself in the future :) .

Comment: I just saw your other question from last month.  It appears the code you are using above is modified from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47843890/2877364).  Is that correct?  If so, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47910269/edit) to link to that source.  That will help others find related information, and will show good faith.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular web page isn't using `<select>` and `<option>`.  That suggests to me that they are using some custom JavaScript to simulate a drop-down list using the illustrated `<div>` and `<span>` elements.  In addition, they are using `onselect` rather than `onclick` to trigger event handlers.

I can't replicate your test case.  However, I did make a test case of my own, and I think it works.  In short, replace `post.Click` with `post.onselect`.  The problem with your code was that it was trying to trigger an `onclick` handler that didn't exist on the target `<span>`!

#### HTML

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function clk() { alert('Dental clicked'); }     // *** So I could see if Click had an effect
    function sel() { alert('Dental selected'); }    // *** Simulate the given testcase
    </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="cboGroupGrid">
        <span class="cboItem" option="0"></span>
        <span class="cboItem" option="1" onselect="sel();" onclick="clk();">Dental</span>
        <span class="cboItem" option="2">Health</span>
        <span class="cboItem" option="3">Unknown Product</span>
    </div>
</body></html>
```

#### VBA

In the code below, `'''` are things I commented out because I didn't have them and they weren't essential to the task as I understand it.

```vb
Public Sub IE_Search_and_Extract()

    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim response As String
    '''response = MsgBox("Login ", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "login")
    '''If response = vbYes Then
    '''    URL = " "
    '''Else
    '''End If
    URL = "prashant.htm"     ' ** Local testcase

    '''Set IE = Get_IE_Window(URL)  ' ** I don't have the code for this function
    '''If IE Is Nothing Then
        Set IE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    '''End If

    With IE
        '''SetForegroundWindow .Hwnd    ' ** I don't have this function
        .navigate URL
        .Visible = True
        While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Wend

        '.document.getElementById("btnLogin").Click

'        While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
'            DoEvents
'        Wend
        'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:5"))
        Set HTMLdoc = .document
    End With

    Dim post As Object, elem As Object
    For Each post In HTMLdoc.getElementsByClassName("cboItem")
        If InStr(post.innerText, "Dental") > 0 Then     ' ** Use a block If, not inline.
            'post.Click    ' ** This does work, and triggers clk()
            post.onselect  ' ** This triggers sel()
            Exit For
        End If
    Next post
End Sub
```

Style suggestion: If you have more than one thing in a `Then` or `Else` block, always use the multiline form.  That way there's no ambiguity about whether the `:` ends the `Then` block or not.

Comment: @prashant Here's what I have.  Would you please read [the MCVE page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you haven't yet?  This will help you get more out of the site.  In this case, your question would have likely been better received if you had included the HTML and VBA of a complete, local testcase.  I had to recreate a testcase by hand-copying from the screenshot you gave, which most folks won't do (and I probably won't do again, now that you know what's up ;) ).  As always, happy hacking!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your code. It's not working. I have attached another screenshot of drop down list. Your code is working fine for the right side drop down list. But not working for the left one.

Comment: @prashant Glad to hear it's working for some things!  If it's working for `Dental` but not for `Ad Hoc Work Search`, would you please upvote+accept this answer and do some research?  Then, if you are still having problems with `Ad Hoc Work Search`, you can ask another question linking to this one.  Try the general techniques I have used and others have mentioned: make a local copy of the HTML file, strip it down to basics, then use the VBA debugger to step through your code.  While stepping, use the Immediate window and the Watch window to see what value your variables have.  Good luck!

Comment: @ cxw Actually it's vice versa. It's working for Adhoc not for Dental. I will try it on immediate window and if get success, let you know. Thanks again !!

Comment: @prashant Interesting!  You're welcome!  Don't forget the Watch window - it will show you the type of a variable, and then you can check that type on MSDN or in the Object Browser.